# Update data in Vuex store rather than replace it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I have the follow data in my Nuxt store/index.js file:

```
export const state = () => ({
    user: {
        status: 'signedin',
        data: {
            'salutation': 'Mr',
            'firstname': 'Test',
            'lastname': 'Person',
            'emailaddress': 'test@test.com'
        }
    }
});
```

I want to update certain values within the 'data' section but not other values...e.g. I want to change 'firstname' to 'David' but keep the rest of the data the same. Please can someone point me in the right direction of how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html). An example of updating a child property can be found here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/jOOvyOr)

In your case, your mutation would look something like this:

```js
{
...
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_FIRST_NAME(state, value) {
      state.user.data.firstname = value;
    }
  }
...
}
// Call the mutation
this.$store.commit('UPDATE_FIRST_NAME', 'David')
```

Comment: Thanks @Tanner. I should have added...my question is a little more complicated than this. I will need to be able to update specific data via a mutation, as the item of data that I will update will be set via a prop passed in to a component. E.g. if my prop 'item' in my component is set to 'firstname', then I'll need to be able to update the 'firstname' value only. Therefore creating a mutation for each item in my data object is not feasible. Any ideas?!

Comment: @aboother so if I understand right, you have a parent component who will pass the `user` object (as it's stored in the Vuex store's state) to its child component, and the child component will perform the update. Am I understanding that right? I have further explanation depending on your answer, so let's start there.

Comment: Yes @Tanner that sounds right. I think I've worked it out! I've added an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've worked this out. My mutation looks like this:

```
{
...
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_USER_DATA(state, value)
    {
        for(const value in values)
        {
            state.user.data[value] = values[value];
        }
    }
  }
...
}
```

I can then update certain data by using the following:

```
this.$store.commit('UPDATE_USER_DATA', {'firstname': 'New'});
```

This will update 'firstname' to 'New' but then keep the rest of the data as is.

I can also update data dynamically, such as if I have a child component that is using the mutation to set a field within my 'data' based on a prop. E.g. if my prop 'field' is set to 'firstname', I can pass that to my mutation by using the following:

```
this.$store.commit('UPDATE_USER_DATA', {this.field: 'New'});
```

This will also update 'firstname' to 'New' but then keep the rest of the data as is.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tanner!